# Get value from object in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have several objects as this structure:
[image]

Then I create a function to update the quantity of the item that matched with search ID :

```
function setQuantityInCartByID(json, itemID, val){
    for(var i in json){
        console.log(json[i].ID);
        if(json[i].ID == itemID){
           json[i].QuantityInCart = val;
           break;
        }
     }
     return json;
}
```

This is my JSON ;

```
{"DepartmentID":12,"CategoryID":117,"BrandID":19,"BrandImage":"&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;","BrandName":"General","ID":708,"Name":"Grand 6Port Power Center","PictureName":"http://111.92.241.110/wwwProducts/unknown.PNG","Notes":"","PriceShow":"$10.00","Price":0,"PriceA":0,"PriceB":0,"PriceC":0,"WebsitePrice":0,"Quantity":2,"QuantityInCart":2,"LastUpdated":"/Date(1378108144050)/","Active":1,"PriceLevel":0,"NewProductImage":"http://111.92.241.110/wwwProducts/newproduct.png","isNewProduct":false,"isInStock":"10 Available in Stock(s)!","NewArrival":0,"ExpireNewArrival":"/Date(-62135596800000)/","NewPromotion":0,"ExpireNewPromotion":"/Date(-62135596800000)/"}

{"DepartmentID":12,"CategoryID":117,"BrandID":19,"BrandImage":"&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;","BrandName":"General","ID":709,"Name":"Grand 6Port Power Center","PictureName":"http://111.92.241.110/wwwProducts/unknown.PNG","Notes":"","PriceShow":"$10.00","Price":0,"PriceA":0,"PriceB":0,"PriceC":0,"WebsitePrice":0,"Quantity":2,"QuantityInCart":2,"LastUpdated":"/Date(1378108144050)/","Active":1,"PriceLevel":0,"NewProductImage":"http://111.92.241.110/wwwProducts/newproduct.png","isNewProduct":false,"isInStock":"10 Available in Stock(s)!","NewArrival":0,"ExpireNewArrival":"/Date(-62135596800000)/","NewPromotion":0,"ExpireNewPromotion":"/Date(-62135596800000)/"}       

{"DepartmentID":12,"CategoryID":117,"BrandID":19,"BrandImage":"&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;","BrandName":"General","ID":710,"Name":"Grand 6Port Power Center","PictureName":"http://111.92.241.110/wwwProducts/unknown.PNG","Notes":"","PriceShow":"$10.00","Price":0,"PriceA":0,"PriceB":0,"PriceC":0,"WebsitePrice":0,"Quantity":2,"QuantityInCart":2,"LastUpdated":"/Date(1378108144050)/","Active":1,"PriceLevel":0,"NewProductImage":"http://111.92.241.110/wwwProducts/newproduct.png","isNewProduct":false,"isInStock":"10 Available in Stock(s)!","NewArrival":0,"ExpireNewArrival":"/Date(-62135596800000)/","NewPromotion":0,"ExpireNewPromotion":"/Date(-62135596800000)/"}
```

Problem : `console.log(json[i].ID);`result is undefined.

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle example?

Comment: You'd have to show us exactly what your `json` argument is.  It looks like your code expects it to be an array of objects or a map of objects, but I'm betting that it's not one of those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The previous link did not seem to apply after I made a fiddle to test this out.  I also updated the first example.

http://jsfiddle.net/AFZhT/

This also assumes that you've done something like `var json = JSON.parse(data)`

If returning an array of objects, your data should be similar to below. This will be passed into the setQuantityInCartByID function as the json parameter:

```
var json = [{"DepartmentID":12,"CategoryID":117,"BrandID":19,"BrandImage":"&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;","BrandName":"General","ID":708,"Name":"Grand 6Port Power Center","PictureName":"http://111.92.241.110/wwwProducts/unknown.PNG","Notes":"","PriceShow":"$10.00","Price":0,"PriceA":0,"PriceB":0,"PriceC":0,"WebsitePrice":0,"Quantity":2,"QuantityInCart":2,"LastUpdated":"/Date(1378108144050)/","Active":1,"PriceLevel":0,"NewProductImage":"http://111.92.241.110/wwwProducts/newproduct.png","isNewProduct":false,"isInStock":"10 Available in Stock(s)!","NewArrival":0,"ExpireNewArrival":"/Date(-62135596800000)/","NewPromotion":0,"ExpireNewPromotion":"/Date(-62135596800000)/"},

    {"DepartmentID":12,"CategoryID":117,"BrandID":19,"BrandImage":"&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;","BrandName":"General","ID":709,"Name":"Grand 6Port Power Center","PictureName":"http://111.92.241.110/wwwProducts/unknown.PNG","Notes":"","PriceShow":"$10.00","Price":0,"PriceA":0,"PriceB":0,"PriceC":0,"WebsitePrice":0,"Quantity":2,"QuantityInCart":2,"LastUpdated":"/Date(1378108144050)/","Active":1,"PriceLevel":0,"NewProductImage":"http://111.92.241.110/wwwProducts/newproduct.png","isNewProduct":false,"isInStock":"10 Available in Stock(s)!","NewArrival":0,"ExpireNewArrival":"/Date(-62135596800000)/","NewPromotion":0,"ExpireNewPromotion":"/Date(-62135596800000)/"} ,      

    {"DepartmentID":12,"CategoryID":117,"BrandID":19,"BrandImage":"&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;","BrandName":"General","ID":710,"Name":"Grand 6Port Power Center","PictureName":"http://111.92.241.110/wwwProducts/unknown.PNG","Notes":"","PriceShow":"$10.00","Price":0,"PriceA":0,"PriceB":0,"PriceC":0,"WebsitePrice":0,"Quantity":2,"QuantityInCart":2,"LastUpdated":"/Date(1378108144050)/","Active":1,"PriceLevel":0,"NewProductImage":"http://111.92.241.110/wwwProducts/newproduct.png","isNewProduct":false,"isInStock":"10 Available in Stock(s)!","NewArrival":0,"ExpireNewArrival":"/Date(-62135596800000)/","NewPromotion":0,"ExpireNewPromotion":"/Date(-62135596800000)/"}];
```

In your page, the following will receive the json object from above and it should now have a length on it.

```
function setQuantityInCartByID(json, itemID, val){
 for(var i in json){
        console.log(json[i].ID);
        if(json[i].ID == itemID){
           json[i].QuantityInCart = val;
           break;
        }
     }
     return json;
}
```

Here's the old way that you seem to have been thinking of:

```
function setQuantityInCartByID(json, itemID, val){
    for(var i = 0; i <json.length;i++)
    {
        console.log(json[i].ID);
        if(json[i].ID === itemID){
           json[i].QuantityInCart = val;
           break;
        }
     }
     return json;
}
```

Comment: This assumes you are returning an array of items in the json object.

Comment: `json.length` is `undefined`.

Comment: @titi, I fixed the code and added a simple jsfiddle to verify it.  You mainly just need to pass in the objects as an array, as I've shown in my example.  (square brackets around all objects, separate objects with commas.)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you need the for in loop. It looks as though your parameter json is already an object, so no need to loop though things, just go json.ID

Answer (score 0):

You can access properties directly, like this:

```
if (json.ID == itemID) {
    json.QuantityInCart = val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have is a javascript object, not an array, and you are addressing properties not indicies.

I think what you are trying to accomplish is access properties of an object without knowing the names. To do that you can use a for ... in loop:

```
for(key in data) {
    if(data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var value = data[key];
        //do something with value;
    }
}
```

If you want to use simple javascript then that time you can use the above code.